# Run As shortcut in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I am setting up cocos2d-x environment in eclipse. While setting up everything has been done properly except that When i press ctrl+f11 It opens up the remote Application setup and asks to setup the new configuration. I want to make it as default Run As Android Application rather than going to project everytime then rightclick and run the android application

Kindly is there any way where i can make shortcut to normal Android Application

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to `window -> preferences`, go to `general -> keys`

There you can define your keyboard shortcuts[image]